# event.preventDefault() not waiting till promise is resolved

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, angular-ui-router

I'm using event.preventDefault() technique to conditionally redirect user to an appropriate state based on a flag value which I'm fetching from backend. Eveything seems to be working fine except that sometimes the actual page is rendered and then redirection happens and that too in very few cases. This render of actual page is also for a very short duration. Following is the code snippet which I'm using:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){

  if (fromState.name === '' && toState.name === "myState"){

    Auth.isLoggedInAsync(function(loggedIn) {
      if (!loggedIn) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('state1');
      } else {
          event.preventDefault();
          Auth.getNextStateForUser()
          .then(function(data) {
            console.log(data.nextState);
            $state.go(data.nextState);
          })
          .catch(function(err){
              console.log(err);
              $state.go(toState.name);
          });
      }
    });
```

The logic which I'm following is, check if a user is logged in, then redirect to state1, else redirect to next appropriate state based on nextstateValue fetched from backend. If some error occurs, open the actual page without any redirection.

I hope I make my myself clear with what I'm doing. Just want to know if the issue which I'm facing is a genuine issue or there is something wrong which I'm doing from my side.

I have posted it on github page as well but it seems that I'm the only one who is facing this issue.

Do check this for more info: 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2088

Thanks

**Edit**: Based on the answers I have updated my code for using ui-router resolve and converted my isLoggedInAsyc to return promise.

```
resolve: {

  promiseState: function(Auth, $state, $q, $stateParams) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    Auth.isLoggedInSync()
    .then(function(isLoggedIn){
        console.log(isLoggedIn);
        if(isLoggedIn) {
          Auth.getNextStateForUser()
              .then(function(data) {
                console.log(data.nextState);
                $state.go(data.nextState);
                deferred.resolve(data);
               })
              .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
                deferred.reject(error);
          }); 
        }

        deferred.resolve(isLoggedIn);
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
        deferred.reject(err);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  }
}
```

And my isLoggedIn() returning promise.

```
  isLoggedInSync: function(callback) {
    var cb = callback || angular.noop;
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if(currentUser.hasOwnProperty('$promise')) {
      currentUser.$promise.then(function() {
        deferred.resolve(true);
        return cb(true);
      }).catch(function() {
        deferred.resolve(false);
        return cb(false);
      });
    } else if(currentUser.hasOwnProperty('role')) {
      deferred.resolve(true);
    } else {
      deferred.resolve(false);
    }
    return deferred.promise;
  }
```

Comment: I think it should be `$event` not `event` for angular codes/events.

Comment: We had this issue in our code before. The best way to handle this sort of logic is to put the role redirection inside of `resolve`. These can be done asynchronously and all resolve handlers *must* be invoked and have results (promises that are returned must also be resolved) before the state can be switched to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @milaenlempera, all Angular events are synchronous and there is no real way for you to nicely handle asynchrony in this instance. We had this issue in our production code and our solution was to use the `resolve` functionality in ui-router. This is how we solved it (plugged into your code obviously)

```
.state({
  name: 'myState',
  resolve: {
    principal: ['Auth', '$state', '$q', function(Auth, $state, $q) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      Auth.isLoggedInAsync(function(loggedIn) {
        if(!isLoggedIn) {
          deferred.resolve($state.go('state1'));
          return;
        }
        return Auth.getNextStateForUser()
          .then(function(data) {
            $state.go(data.nextState);
           })
          .catch(function(error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
          });
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    }]
  }
});
```

I'd recommend turning `Auth.isLoggedInAsync` to return a promise.

Also, your original code will cause an infinite loop if `Auth.getNextStateForUser()` is rejected. It will attempt to go to the state with the name `toState.name`, which is the state that just caused the error, which will cause another error and cause it to go to `toState.name`....

Because `resolve` cascades, you can implement child states if you want to share rules for permissions. It does really suck that there is no way to just put a property on the state and handle asynchronous permission checking elsewhere, but that's the hand we have been dealt at the moment.

As per comments, here's an example of promise chaining with your amended code.

```
  promiseState: ['Auth', '$state', function(Auth, $state) {
    return Auth.isLoggedInSync()
      .then(function(isLoggedIn) {
        if(isLoggedIn) {
          return Auth.getNextStateForUser().then(function(data) {
            return data.nextState;
          });
        }
        // If the user isn't logged in, return the state that you should go to instead
        return 'state1';
      })
      .then(function(nextState) {
        return $state.go(nextState);
      });
  }]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking out time to help. I have updated my code based on your logic and converted my isLoggedIn() function to return promise. Can you please take a look at it and tell me if it is correct ? Being new to the concept, just want to cross-verify if I'm doing right ? Thanks

Comment: solution with resolve is possible, but i thing better is use data attribute in route definition `data: {
          authRoles: ['ROLE_ADMIN']
        }` (see my solution link in my answer). Resolve has different purpose (load locals dependencies for controller)

Comment: I have looked at your answer and this was originally the first route I took. However, I found that this did not work as desired and was very flaky and didn't work smoothly *at all* when you had asynchronous authentication. That is why I suggested this method. Your example only works if you have synchronous authentication. When we used this method we would regularly get infinite digest cycles and/or incorrect results due to the asynchronous nature of our login.

Comment: @dark_shadow with regards to your updated solution, there's no need to use `$q` if your `AuthSvc.isLoggedIn` returns a promise, you can instead use promise chaining.

Comment: @DanPantry: Can you please show me what exactly are you trying to say ? I'm fairly new to node.js and still getting with the concepts of promise and $q. It will be great if you can show me with some code snippets. Thanks

Comment: @dark_shadow I've updated my answer with a promise chaining example.

Answer (score 0):

Angular events are synchoronously.
If you need stop it, you must do it synchronously in event handler function.
In you example is asynchronously checked login, meanwhile routing continue. This is why you see page and to redirect happens afterwards.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
    function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){

      // here check if route can be display (synchronously)
      // or event.preventDefault()

      Auth.isLoggedInAsync(function(loggedIn) {
      if (loggedIn) {
        // continue to original route or go to state by server data
      } else {
        // redirect to login page
      }  
});
```

you can be inspired in my solution [here](https://bitbucket.org/angular_cz/beerapp-codio/src/b57231a381378a3f3d2eef3ccdaa87ab7f31f22f/src/common/cz/angular/auth/adapter/uiRouter.js)

Comment: @milaenlempera: Thanks a lot for taking out time to help. I have updated my code with synchronized manner of doing things. Can you please take a look at it and tell me if it is correct ? Being new to the concept, just want to cross-verify if I'm doing right ? Thanks

Comment: At first glance it looks OK.